# Android, fragment transaction with container object instead of id

Tags: android, fragment

Now it looks like:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

I need to use container object (something like this) :

```
FrameLayout fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) My.frameLayout;
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, if the `My.frameLayout` is currently in view hierarchy. You can try something like this:

```
FrameLayout fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout) My.frameLayout;
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragmentContainer.getId(), fragment).commit();
```